Beamer Metropolis frametitle at the bottom
Is it possible to have the frametitle be at the bottom of the frame instead of the top ?
I'm a teacher and I use the frametitle to remind students of which section we are in but it's less important than the students at the back being able to see all the content...
Additionnaly, is it possible to 'get' the current (sub)section title automaticaly as the frame title ? With it's number if possible.
    \documentclass[aspectratio=169,french,compact,mathserif]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\lipsum[23]

\lipsum[23]
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Instead of trying to move the frametitle to the bottom, you can show the (sub)section in the footline:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,french,compact,mathserif]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}


\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=\paperwidth,%
      leftskip=1.6ex,%
      rightskip=\the\glueexpr 1.6ex plus 1fill\relax,%
    ]{frametitle}%
    \moloch@frametitlestrut@start%
    \insertsectionnumber.~\insertsectionhead\
    \ifnum\thesubsection>0
      - \insertsubsectionnumber.~\insertsubsectionhead
    \fi
    \moloch@frametitlestrut@end%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[23]

\lipsum[23]
\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[23]

\lipsum[23]
\end{frame}


\end{document}



The idea of simply moving the frametitle to the bottom was also to still have the progressbar ... but your solution is great already (for some reason it doesn't work with moloch for me but I was able to adapt it for metropolis and it worked).
Is it possible to have the possibility to have it replaced by the frametitle if one is given ?

@Redji Don't use metropolis. It is outdated and causes a lot of headaches for the current beamer code. Replacements like moloch are much better.

Do you have an idea why I get an error if I use it with moloch then ?

@Redji Which error do you get?

I get 9 undefined control sequence from the lines with \moloch@frametitlestrut ...

Is your moloch theme up-to-date? Please compile the code as it is shown in my answer and add the resulting .log file to your question.

I have TexLive 2024 ... How can I add the log to my question ? if I copy the content it greatly exceeds the characters limit.
